# PHP force download - files larger then 100MB will download only few bites

Tags: php, apache, kohana

After my hosting provider upgraded server (Debian) and PHP (from 5.2.6 to 5.3.2) I am having problems with my file download script on our website. Files smaller then 100MB will download fine, but file larger then 100MB will download only as 156 Bytes file ... Here is my download script:

```
class Download_Controller extends Website_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
          $file     = $_GET['file'];
          $filORM   = ORM::factory('file')->where('filename', $file)->find();

          if ($filORM->loaded and $filORM->deleted=='N' and file_exists(APPPATH.'downloads/'.$file) ) {
            //we can serve file download
            $this->auto_render = false;

            $filORM->counter = $filORM->counter + 1;
            $filORM->save();

            $dl = ORM::factory('download');
            $dl->download_file_id = $filORM->id;
            $dl->created = time();
            $dl->country_id = $this->country->id;
            $dl->ip = $this->_getRealIpAddr();
            $dl->browser = Kohana::user_agent('browser');
            $dl->version = Kohana::user_agent('version');
            $dl->platform = Kohana::user_agent('platform');
            $dl->save();

            return download::force(APPPATH.'downloads/'.$file);
          }
          else {
            $this->download_error();
          }

        }
        else {
            //else here we load download center UI
            $this->section();
        }
    }   
}
```

I am using Kohana PHP framework. Version 2.3.x.

Comment: Have you some access to the server? Or is it an managed server?

Comment: What's the contents of those 156-byte files? Anything special?

Comment: Mostly EXE (application installers), also tried a ZIP file of photos. Same result. You can try it here: http://dewesoft.com/download?file=DEWESoft_FULL_7_0_4.exe (130MB) or http://dewesoft.com/download?file=ds-minitaur-photos.zip (194MB). This one will download fine since it's under 100MB http://dewesoft.com/download?file=SIRIUS_photos_Press_Quality.zip (18MB)

Comment: This is what I downloaded, the error message is quite clear: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 141637633 bytes) in /home/www-data/system/helpers/download.php on line 93"

Comment: @Maerlyn where did you see that error?

Comment: I opened the downloaded file in a text editor.

Comment: I have currently made an workaround by setting php_value memory_limit 300M to .htaccess. I know this is not a good solution, but will do until I make a proper upgrade into download script! Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, you gave me example links, I tried one, and that 156-byte file I downloaded contained this:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 141637633 bytes) in /home/www-data/system/helpers/download.php on line 93

It's quite clear - PHP ran out of memory. I presume while upgrading they also changed the memory_limit in php.ini. Short-term solution is to change it back to it's original (higher) value.

For downloading large files, you should look into [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) (also available for servers other than apache), that involves setting a special http header, and leaving the work to the webserver instead of php.

Answer (score 0):

If Kohana's `download::force()` works the same way as in probably any other framework - PHP simply cannot or isn't allowed to hold more than 100MB of data in memory.

Comment: It worked flawlessly before the server upgrade...? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know what`s the code of `download::force()`, but I think that it loads entire file into memory and PHP stops executing with error like `Allowed memory size is exhausted`. You need to load and output your file by small chunks checking if client aborted connection.

**Update**

Your file contains `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 141637633 bytes) in /home/www-data/system/helpers/download.php on line 93`. So, as I wrote, output it by small chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to `readfile(APPPATH.'downloads/'.$file)` and then `exit()` directly without `return`, then you will not be bound to memory issues anymore